# How to encode url to prevent Illegal Character in url

Tags: android, http, url

I have to hit an `url` : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0&destinations=19.0,72.0&mode=driving&sensor=false

I am getting the following errer:

```
11-14 14:14:21.154: E/AndroidRuntime(2813): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 71: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0&destinations=19.0,72.0&mode=driving&sensor=false
```

I have also tried `URLencodedUtils.format()` but I am getting the same error.

Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("origins=0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0|0.0,0.0&destinations=19.0,72.0&mode=driving&sensor=false", "utf-8");
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?" + query;
```

Comment: I Got this by Doint this:`String    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=";
     try {
   url = url + URLEncoder.encode(sourceLatLng, "utf-8") + "&destinations=" + URLEncoder.encode(destinLatLng, "utf-8") + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";
   
   Log.v(Commons.TAG, url);
   
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }`